# PowerPoint 2010/2013 how to override the photo album default template/layout

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, default-settings

I am trying to find a way to override or customize the default layout/template that PowerPoint uses when I insert a photo album (Ribbon menu->Insert->Photo Album [in the images section]).  We will be creating a number of photo albums that will require a custom title slide followed by an overview slide followed by one or more slides containing images followed by a final slide with boilerplate language.

The default theme (meaning the one we get if we don't select one) creates a slide with the text "Photo Album" and the author's name followed by slide(s) containing the photos.

If we pick a template/layout for the insert photo album, it uses the theme from the template, but overrides any of the default content that was part of the template.

We need to  support a wide array of users, so the simpler we can make this the better!